# What is the relationship between Mohr's Circle and Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

While I was studying PCA, I was told that it is related to Mohr's Circle. I don't know what that means. I don't know if they are related or not. I was just told, so I want to make sure here.

If they are related, what is the relationship between [Mohr's Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohr's_circle) and [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)?

Comment: This is wild speculation on my part, but consider the following quote from Wikipedia's article on Mohr's circle: "...acting on the _rotated coordinate system_. In other words, the circle is the locus of points that represent the state of stress on individual planes at all their orientations, where the axes represent the _principal axes_ of the stress element." -- this seems like it might be related to PCA in that both involve a transformation of the coordinate system and a search for _principal_ axes/components (eigenvalues) of the data. I have no idea though, just wild speculation.

Comment: Thank you for the words. That helps me have a clue of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Mohr's Circle is a graphical method to calculate principal stresses. So basically, you calculate the principal components for a 2D or 3D problem. The nice thing is that you can do that with very simple calculations and drawing so you don't need a computer. You know engineers had to be smart and creative before machine learning. :D